# If the ratio of AM and HM of two positive real numbers (a and b) is m:n. Find a:b.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$AM = \frac{a+b}2\text{ and }HM = \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

Therefore $AM/HM= (a+b)^2/4ab=m/n$.

I'm not able to proceed further. What do I need to do to get $a/b$? Thanks in advance. :)

Also, the answer is $\dfrac { \sqrt{m} + \sqrt{m-n}}{ \sqrt{m} - \sqrt{m-n}}$ how do I get it?

Comment: If the problem is well-posed, then you should be able to replace $\{a,b\}$ by $\{ka,kb\}$ for any positive real $k$.  Hence, you may assume without loss that $b=1$.

Comment: Your calculation for $AM/HM$ is incorrect.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typing mistake.

Comment: @vadim123 Can you pls elaborate on it?

Comment: @HarshalGajjar, please check my answer.  :)

Comment: The geometric mean of two numbers has the beautiful property that it is the same as the geometric mean of their arithmetic and harmonic means. $G=\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{AH}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AM = \frac{a + b}{2}$$

$$HM = \frac{2ab}{a + b}$$

$$\frac{AM}{HM} = \frac{(a + b)^2}{4ab} = \frac{m}{n}$$

Let $m = (a + b)^2$ and let $n = 4ab$.  Then $m - n = (a - b)^2$.

Therefore,

$$a + b = \sqrt{m}$$
$$a - b = \sqrt{m - n}.$$

Consequently,

$$a = \frac{\sqrt{m} + \sqrt{m - n}}{2}$$
$$b = \frac{\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{m - n}}{2}.$$

Finally,

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\sqrt{m} + \sqrt{m - n}}{\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{m - n}},$$

as desired.

QED.

Comment: How can you prove this for n numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

If we replace $\{a,b\}$ by $\{ka,kb\}$, then the ratio AM/HM does not change: $$\frac{(ka+kb)^2}{4(ka)(kb)}=\frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}=\frac{m}{n}$$

Hence, use $k=\frac{1}{b}$, and set $c=\frac{a}{b}$.  Now, it suffices to solve the problem for $$\frac{(c+1)^2}{4c}=\frac{m}{n}$$

This simplifies to a quadratic equation in $c$.  Let me know if you have trouble finishing the problem from here.